how would you motivate an unusual v4l2-ctl --list-devices output?
I'm using v4l2-ctl --list-devices for enumerating available camares, parsing the output in python code. I find it hard to motivate why it would return a non-zero exit code along with this output:
$ ll /dev/video*
3 Apr  9 00:35 /dev/video3
4 Apr  9 00:35 /dev/video4
5 Apr  9 00:35 /dev/video5
6 Apr  9 00:35 /dev/video6

$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices    
Logitech Webcam C930e (usb-0000:00:14.0-1):
        /dev/video3
        /dev/video4
        /dev/media0

Brio 500 (usb-0000:00:14.0-2):
        /dev/video5
        /dev/video6
        /dev/media1

Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.

$ echo $?
1

Is there a reason for v4l2 to insist that /dev/video0 be available? or does this look like some kernel issue of an ambiguous state for /dev/video0?
The error line "Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting" comes out on stderr, while the rest of the output is as it normally would appear.
Just curious.
